# Login to increase integer var from min value to max value using jquery scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, jsfiddle

I'm struggling to see the how the logic is working inside the `parseInt`.

Would anyone be able to help with some logic (if possible) to replace the current `-x/10` below.

Rather than starting at `0`, and then adding to it. I am trying to achieve spanning between `30%` and `70%`.

```
$('ARTICLE A.thumb>SPAN').scroll(function(){
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(this).css('background-position','center '+parseInt(-x/10)+'%');
});
```

So the idea is when I'm at the top of the page, the integer will be `30%` and as i slowly scroll down the page, this will increase, but when I reach the bottom of the page, it will be `70%`. So the min is `30` and the max is `70`.

My logic understanding is not great as I'm more UI focused but would really appreciate some help on this one.

I've made this into a fidde, but I'm trying to output as HTML string so you people can see what is happening. But I can't even get this work now :/

https://jsfiddle.net/w6h2z52n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your JSFiddle wasn't pulling in jQuery - ooops!

Also the scroll should occur on the window element so I have updated the JSFiddle to reflect this -

https://jsfiddle.net/w6h2z52n/7/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    // get our distance from top
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();

  // determine our percentage. The higher the
  // speed the slower the percentage will increment
    var speed = 30;
    var perc = x > 0 ? parseInt(x / speed) : 0;

  // now convert our percentage to between 30 and 70
  if(perc <= 30) perc = 30;
  if(perc >= 70) perc = 70;

  $('.value SPAN').html('background-position: center ' + perc + '%');
});
```

I have added a check in to make sure the percentage is between 30 & 70 although this may not be exactly what you are looking for and some kind of logical operation to translate the percentage to a value between 30 & 70 may be better but let me know!

**EDIT**

This was a nice little challenge so I gave it another go, it's just a case of mathematics... give it a go!

https://jsfiddle.net/w6h2z52n/10/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    // get our distance from top
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();

  // work out our containers height
  var $container = $('.container');

    // determine percentage from top of page
  var percFromTop = ( x / $container.outerHeight() ) * 100;
  percFromTop = Math.floor(percFromTop);

  // now convert our percentage to between 30 and 70
  perc = Math.floor( 30 + (30 / 70) * percFromTop );

  $('.value SPAN').html('background-position: center ' + perc + '%');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris this is perfect! Wow appreciate your time working this one out, I 100% would of never got there. +1 would give more if I could.

Answer (score -1):

uh this really made me interested, i solved it the following way

```
// remember last x
var lastx = 0

// the overall height
var overallheight = $(document).height()

// 70 - 30 == 50, so divide overallheight through 50 to get the "1%" in px 
var unit = (overallheight / 50)

// initial percent
var perc = 30

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();

  // if scroll down more than lastx + "1%"
  if(x >=  lastx + unit){

     // determine how many percent(step) the actual "gap" is (rounded)  
     gap = x - lastx;
     step = parseInt( gap / unit)

     // add percent
     perc += step
     lastx = x
  }

  // same reversed for scrolling back up
  if(x <=  lastx + unit){
     gap = lastx - x;
     step = parseInt( gap / unit)
     perc -= step
     lastx = x
  }

  $('.value').html('background-position: center '+parseInt(-x/10)+'%');
});
```

for me this attempt feels quite smooth, but there is some small error due to the round(), maybe extracheck perc does not get smaller than 30 greater than 70

https://jsfiddle.net/w6h2z52n/11/

Comment: Thank you John to for attempting this, it was a tricky one and I could not quite get your fiddle to work right. Chris managed to nail it. But you help is also much appreciated! Thanks